# how add image upload functionality to existing add/update function in codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, image-uploading

I've Add/Update function in my controller and I want to add image upload functionality to it and save the file path to database and than want to display it but I don't know where to add file upload functionality
here is the code

```
public function edit($id = NULL) {
        //Fetch a page or set new one
        if ($id) {
            $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get($id);
          count($this->data['page']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'Page Could not be found';
            }
            else {
                $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_new();
           }
        $id == NULL || $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get($id);
        //Pages for dropdown
        $this->data['pages_no_parents'] = $this->page_m->get_no_parents();
        //dump($this->data['pages_no_parents']);
        //Setup form
        $rules = $this->page_m->rules;

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
        //Process the form

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array(
                'title',
                'slug',
                'order',
                'body',
                'template',
                'parent_id',
                'filename'
            ));
            $this->page_m->save($data, $id);
            //echo $data->filename;
            redirect('admin/page');
        }
        //Load the view    
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/page/edit';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
```

Comment: its my page model which is extending from My_Model which is having all curd operation

Comment: you can add upload functionality  after checking form validation i mean after if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

Comment: yes I tried to add this functionality and borrowed the code from ellislab
but problem is that at the time when save function is called I've two $data arrays one for file name to be uploaded and other is for the whole form data and I don't know how to merge both of these data arrays